# Running a job every 10 seconds while the other runs every 1 minute

Tags: cron

I have one job that's supposed to run every 10 seconds, and then I have another one that's supposed to run every 60 seconds. However, it seems that the one that's supposed to run every 10 seconds only runs ***after*** the one that runs every 60 seconds... so technically it only runs once per minute.

Here's the order that they're in:

```
* * * * * ( sleep 10 ; /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /root/script.rb')
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /root/another_script.rb'
```

I thought these were going to run parallel with each other if it ever needed to. Apparently I must not be doing something right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first entry on your `crontab` row will be executed each minute, sleeps 10 seconds, then exit. Moreover, the second entry will be executed one time *each hour*. I strongly suggest you reading `crontab` man page.

Answer (score 2):

These are the cron fields (from `man -i 5 crontab`):

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

As you can see, there is no 'second' field. To run a job every 10 seconds, you have to use a loop in your script. One option would be to run the script from cron every minute, and have the script run at 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50 seconds.

Here is a template you could use for this script:

```
for i in $(seq 0 5); do echo $i; sleep 10; done
```